# Grid View of images in a Content

Tags: nodes

I want to display images in grid view. I have designed a view which can display each album in grid view. Here album is a content type. The problem is that inside album I can see list view of images. I have selected unlimited number of value  in image filed under album content type. Below is the screenshot-

[image]

Comment: Are you using Views or is this just a field being displayed?

Comment: The above screenshot is not the view. It is just a field. Using views we can display it in grid but what if I want to display images in grid in a content type i.e. article.

Comment: You can do it with CSS. http://alijafarian.com/responsive-image-grids-using-css/

Comment: @betherwisser: You can answer the question :) also please mention how to add this `css` a content type :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [do it with CSS](http://alijafarian.com/responsive-image-grids-using-css/).

You add CSS to your theme. If you're using a theme like Zen that has SASS, you can add the new rules to your SASS file(s) and compile them to CSS. There is [documentation for adding CSS to pages](https://www.drupal.org/node/171209) on Drupal.org.

Comment: Okay :) Thanks a ton. By the way I am using [Responsive Blog](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_blog) theme. The demo of this theme is available [here](http://responsive-blog.techsaran.com)